# Dynamic Nav Dropdown of Posts

Tags: wordpress

What would be the best method to implement a dynamically generated menu off the primary nav showing all posts?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the `WP_Query` to sort all posts:**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Then loop through the posts and add your html markup:**

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
      // your menu item here
endwhile;
endif;
```

***HINT**

*In order to add this at the beginning of your menu you can use the* [wp_nav_menu_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/)

To target the menu alter the filter name to include the menu ID. In my case the menu ID is `menu-main` so I use only `main` like this `wp_nav_menu_main_items`.

**Working example:**

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_main_items', 'prefix_add_menu_item', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Add Menu Item to start of menu
 */
function prefix_add_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
       $start_menu_item =  '<li class="menu-item">Posts</li>';
       $new_items = $start_menu_item . $items;
       return $new_items;
}
```

**Combined for desired result:**

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_main_items', 'prefix_add_menu_item', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Add Menu Item to start of menu
 */
function prefix_add_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

       $start_menu_item =  '<li class="menu-item">Posts';
       $start_menu_item .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
       if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
       $start_menu_item .= '<li class="menu-item">'.get_the_title().'</li>';
       endwhile;
       endif;
       $start_menu_item .= '</ul>';
       $start_menu_item .= '</li>';

       $new_items = $start_menu_item . $items;
       return $new_items;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to inject this into an existing menu that I created via the WordPress admin GUI?  If I already have level 1 created and simply want this in level 2 off of a specific menu item.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use wp_nav_menu_filter to inject the code